# Magento: how to automatically add JS file after certain other JS files?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to include a JavaScript file after certain other JavaScript files. Normally, I would just include it in the XML file using syntax like:

```
<action method="addJs"><script>myfile.js</script></action>
```

or

```
<action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>myfile.js</name></action>
```

in the correct order, so files are included the way I want.

The point is, though, I won't know how many times I have to include my file. To be more specyfic, I'm trying to include a file with jQuery.noConflict() after every instance of jquery*.js file. The website I'm working on is still under development and there might still be added some new extensions that include their own jquery library (and I might not even be aware of that as I am not the only person working on the project).

Is there any event on including js file when rendering the layout on the frontend or maybe there is some method I could rewrite to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to add an inclusion of script X after every inclusion of script Y, is to modify the function that does the adding.

Open app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php, and modify the function getCssJsHtml. Like this:

```
public function getCssJsHtml()
{
    // separate items by types
    $lines  = array();
    foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $item) {
        if (!is_null($item['cond']) && !$this->getData($item['cond']) || !isset($item['name'])) {
            continue;
        }
        $if     = !empty($item['if']) ? $item['if'] : '';
        $params = !empty($item['params']) ? $item['params'] : '';
        switch ($item['type']) {
            case 'js':        // js/*.js
            case 'skin_js':   // skin/*/*.js
            case 'js_css':    // js/*.css
            case 'skin_css':  // skin/*/*.css
                $lines[$if][$item['type']][$params][$item['name']] = $item['name'];
                if(stripos($item['name'], 'jquery') !== false)$lines[$if][$item['type']][$params]['2_'.$item['name']] = $yourfilename;
                break;
            default:
                $this->_separateOtherHtmlHeadElements($lines, $if, $item['type'], $params, $item['name'], $item);
                break;
        }
    }
...
```

You see I've added a check to see whether the file being added is jquery (`stripos($item['name'], 'jquery') !== false`), and if so, add a new item right after it with the path `$yourfilename`.

Magento was supposed to already have the ability to sort skin files, but that a) relies on everyone supplying a sort attribute, and b) never actually worked properly in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Hy,

Magento by default is not allowing you to do that, in order to be able to add files in a specific order (css or javascript in header) you have to customize the core.

Create a custom module, where you rewrite the page/html_head block:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Koncz_Utility>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Koncz_Utility>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <class>Koncz_Utility_Block</class>
            <page>
                <rewrite>
                    <html_head>Koncz_Utility_Block_Page_Html_Head</html_head>
                </rewrite>
            </page>          
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

and add 2 custom functions: **addItemFirst** and **addItemAfter**

```
class Koncz_Utility_Block_Page_Html_Head extends Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head {
/*
 * Adds a head element into the first position, usage same as for addItem ;)
 */

public function addItemFirst($type, $name, $params = null, $if = null, $cond = null) {
    if ($type === 'skin_css' && empty($params)) {
        $params = 'media="all"';
    }

    $firstElement = array();
    $firstElement[$type . '/' . $name] = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $name,
        'params' => $params,
        'if' => $if,
        'cond' => $cond,
    );

    $this->_data['items'] = array_merge($firstElement, $this->_data['items']);

    return $this;
}

/*
* Adds a custom css, or js file after the $type, if it was found! $type=js/jquery/jquery.js  <= or skin_js/path 
*/
public function addItemAfter($after, $type, $name, $params = null, $if = null, $cond = null) {
    if ($type === 'skin_css' && empty($params)) {
        $params = 'media="all"';
    }

    $firstElement = array();
    $firstElement[$type . '/' . $name] = array(
        'type' => $type,
        'name' => $name,
        'params' => $params,
        'if' => $if,
        'cond' => $cond,
    );

    if (array_key_exists($after, $this->_data['items'])) :
        // get the position 
        $pos = 1;
        foreach ($this->_data['items'] as $key => $options) :
            if ($key == $after) :
                break;
            endif;
            $pos +=1;
        endforeach;

        array_splice($this->_data['items'], $pos, 0, $firstElement);

    endif;


    return $this;
}
```

}

After this in your local.xml you can use the following: (This will add jquery.js in the first position and jquery.no-conflict.js after jquery in 2nd position). {{ Also it worth mentioning that your skin_js files will be added after js types! }} So use js and not skin_js for the base js files.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>        
        <update handle="add_jquery_elegant_way" />
    </default>
    <add_jquery_elegant_way>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItemFirst"><type>js</type><script>jquery/jquery.js</script></action>
            <action method="addItemAfter">
                <after>js/jquery/jquery.js</after>
                <type>js</type>
                <script>jquery/jquery.no-conflict.js</script>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </add_jquery_elegant_way>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to edit jquery*.js, and add this at the end of the file:

```
$jq=jQuery.noConflict();
```

then you would just use $jq to access the jQuery object, and when ever jquery.js is included it's automatically set to noConflict mode.

Comment: Wouldn't that break the second jquery inclusion? If they are expecting $ to be jQuery, and this forces it to automatically reset to prototype, you'll break the script.

Comment: no this means you dont use $ for Jquery to avoid breaking the prototype JS. If you add extra jquery functions you refer to $jq('..')

Comment: obviously if you are using $jq as a jQuery reference you shouldn't be a moron and then try and use $. the point is to leave $ for prototype as the default library is prototype so we don't want to break standard code by adding in jquery.

Comment: Right, but what if a later user adds another jquery.js, and tries to use $? You imply that their code would not longer be able to use $ the way they expect it to. Remember OP said it needs to be able to handle future developers doing their own thing.

Comment: why would you add another jquery file that would be idiotic and cause different issues. You only want to load the library once.

Comment: Read the question. I quote: "The website I'm working on is still under development and there might still be added some new extensions that include their own jquery library"

Comment: but if any decent module includes it's own Jquery it should also take care of noConflict for you. you shouldn't ever include multiple jquery libs even in dev setups it's just stupid and will cause problems regardless of using noConflict :)

Comment: Yep, that is completely true. Unfortunately, not all developers are as smart as you, and all too often make some really stupid choices. Sometimes a good dev needs to plan ahead, and put safeguards in place to handle other people's mistakes as well as can be done.

Answer (score -1):

you can put the instruction manualy on header.phtml.
app/design/frontend/yoursite/path/template/page/html/header.phtml.
And what you put there go to html after you js include.

Comment: The problem is that I need to include my js file (or just a <script>) several times between other .js files. I won't be able to achieve it in the template files.

Comment: @BartoszGórski No have way, or include manualy on order and way you want in .phtml file. Or use default behavior from magento and use xml. =/